# Date.today.end_of_day not working as mysql converting millisecond to whole number

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model name `Event` and it has two fields `start_time` and `end_time`. When I assign event end time to `Date.today.end_of_day`, then it should save event end time as `2015-12-24 23:59:59` but it is saving as `2015-12-25 00:00:00`.

Secondly when I looked at the mysql query it is displaying

> INSERT INTO `events` (`name`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('event', '2015-12-24 00:00:00.000000', '2015-12-25 23:59:59.999999', '2015-12-24 07:03:11.559727', '2015-12-24 07:03:11.559727')

my `mysql` version is `5.6.28`. Earlier it was saving as expected but now its not with new mysql version. Mysql is converting millisecond to whole number. How do resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post your query code.

Comment: This is simple `Event.create(:name => 'event', :start_time => Date.today.begining_of_day, :end_time => Date.today.end_of_day)`